# Using php in a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, echo

I would like to use php in a wordpress post. I have installed a plugin that allows php to be used in these tags: `[php][/php]`

I am trying to create this link:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.co.uk/?affid=[php]global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); echo $current_user->user_login;[/php]" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"></a>
```

This code doesnt work, but when I simply post the php on its own like so:

```
[php] global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); echo $current_user->user_login;[/php]
```

it works.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is _never_ a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: That's probably dependent on that specific plugin (you didn't mention which) and how Wordpress matches those bbcode-esque tags. Please [flag] your question for moderator love if you want it moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (likely to get more expert advise there).

Comment: Did you add the special tags in HTML or VISUAL view of you WYSIWYG editor? My guess is that it should only work under HTML. Can you CTRL+U and paste the source of the link that "doesn't work"? THx.

Comment: Sorry the plugin is http://www.hitreach.co.uk/wordpress-plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/

Comment: I've inputted it into HTML and it makes no different. Sorry for the poor description im not very experienced. What I meant by doesnt work is that it just doesnt show up in the post. In fact it removes the sidebar too

Comment: If it removes the sidebar there's probably an error that's stopping execution altogether - if it's a development site, try setting WP_DEBUG to true in your wp-config.php and see if that sheds any light on the problem.  Though as @mario says you might have more luck getting this moved to the wordpress stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Exec-PHP Plugin:

http://bluesome.net/post/2005/08/18/50/

You can insert the usual php tags instead of short codes, i.e. `<?php your code here ?>` inside your post and it will work like in a normal php file. I am using it with WP 3.3 and I have no issues with it.

Writing PHP in a Post is difficult as it is not designed to be a code editor. You can write your code in a free editor like Notepad++ and when you are sure you have no syntax errors simply copy-paste it into the post.